# "http method not bound to view" when documenting class-based view in drf_yasg

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

Previously, I documented my function-based views like this:

```python
@swagger_auto_schema(
    operation_id='ChangePassword',
    methods=['POST'],
    request_body=ChangePasswordSerializer,
    responses={
        '200': 'empty response body',
    })
def change_password(request):
    # code here
```

We then switched our views to class-based, so I simply copy-pasted the documentation decorator over to the `post` method:

```python
class UserChangePasswordView(APIView):
    @swagger_auto_schema(
        operation_id='ChangePassword',
        methods=['POST'],
        request_body=ChangePasswordSerializer,
        responses={
            '200': 'empty response body',
        })
    def post(self, request):
        # code here
```

However, on running this decorator, [`drf_yasg`](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg) threw the exception

```python
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/drf_yasg/utils.py", line 126, in decorator
    assert all(mth in available_methods for mth in _methods), "http method not bound to view"
```

What is going on? What does this error message mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in [source core](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/blob/master/src/drf_yasg/utils.py#L21-L22) of [`drf-yasg`](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg) it's mentioned

> `method` and `methods` are mutually exclusive and must only be present when decorating a view method that more than one HTTP request method.

So `methods` would be valid if your `UserChangePasswordView.post()` handled more than one method.

Comment: Thank you! That is reasonable and I have no idea how I overlooked that. I still find it difficult to derive the fix from the error message though.

Comment: @ThePadawan drf-yasg is new package, and for it's age it's amazing how beautiful it is. You can raise new issue and maybe make contribution to it for making it more readable. Glad i helped!

Comment: Thank you, I will look into contributing!

Comment: Hey! author of said library here - just now noticed this question; will look into adding a helpful assertion, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that specifying the HTTP method of the view both in the decorator and implicitly via the name of the method to which the decorator is applied is not valid.

The solution is to simply remove the `methods` key from the decorator:

```python
class UserChangePasswordView(APIView):
    @swagger_auto_schema(
        operation_id='ChangePassword',
        request_body=ChangePasswordSerializer,
        responses={
            '200': 'empty response body',
        })
    def post(self, request):
        # code here
```